# javascript: html inline events - get the event name from its calling

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div onclick="func(this)" onmouseover="func(this)">
```

is there a way to know which way (by click or mouseover) `func()` was called from code above without changing it (the code above)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In `func()`, you can do:

```
event.type
```

but it won't work in FireFox as it isn't exposed to the global scope as opposed to others.

Comment: @j08691, yes, I suppose so

Comment: Right, so you might want to note that when calling the function, in order to get the type, you have to pass the `event`, like `func(event,this)`. If the OP tried what he has, `func(this)`, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @j08691, no it works mate. `event` object holds the data whether passed or not. http://jsfiddle.net/Nr5EJ/

Comment: Contrast [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M6maw/) with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pybLE/)

Comment: @j08691 both outputting `undefined` 2 times. I don't seem to understand your point

Comment: Bad second link, fixed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pybLE/1/ the point is OP doesn't need to explicitly include `event` in his arguments, although it is considered good paractice, unless he wants to support FF. He has said in his question "without changing the html" and my fiddle shows that even without including it, it works correctly `:)`

Comment: the very object `event` contains the data.

Comment: indeed `event` is defined in Chrome even without passing it, but sadly not in Firefox, I need Firefox too...

Answer (score 0):

[event.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.type) gives you the event name. For this work in FF you need to pass event as as the input to the method

jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rY4/1/)

`<div onclick="javascript:func(event,this)" onmouseover="javascript:func(event,this)">
    <span>Hi</span>
</div>`